# Open Source Packages Implementing Continuous Wavelet and Scaling Functions

Tags: open-source, wavelet

I'm looking for an open source software package that provides a fast evaluation of continuous Daubechies/Symmlet wavelet/scaling functions.

GSL only has the discrete wavelets, and PyWavelets comes close to what I want, in that it gives a gives the values of the functions on an equispaced grid of whatever refinement you desire.

Comment: In case you need to roll your own I can recommend memoization, with it my program almost got fast enough.

Comment: Did you check out [Wavelab](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~wavelab/)? Matlab package, open source, Stanford University.

Comment: @Emil: Very interested, do you have a link?

Comment: @GertVdE: I don't have Matlab. Perhaps I could read the source without being able to run it; in any case the documentation at the link is broken.

Comment: @user14717: it is just a technique. I used it to precompute a filter bank. (it saves function output keyed by the function arguments).

Comment: @Emil: This? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: @user14717: yes, that way it is only slow the first time one computes the filter bank (I tried to make a wavelet implementation for any kernel, not just the popular ones). There are probably costly convolutions as well, I haven't looked into making them faster.

Comment: @user14717: I was able to download the PDF documentation following the link on the page. This is the [direct link to the pdf](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~wavelab/Wavelab_850/AboutWaveLab.pdf)